# How to create language-dictionary database from text file?

Tags: html, xml, database

I have a large text file, which is an Italian-English dictionary. A typical line is:

```
Mazzapícchio, a long pole that fishers vse to bob vp and down for Eeles, and also to make fish to stirre. Also a kind of meate or custard in some parts of Italie made with milke and egges.
```

*(Yes, it's a 17th-century dictionary.)*

**I'm looking for the best/easiest way to turn this into a searchable database.**
The search would need to ignore the diacritics; with everything up to the first comma as the 'entry'. There are some cross-references, e.g.: `Mefíte, as Mephíte.`

My first thought is simply to turn it into HTML, with anchor tags for the word/phrase up to the first comma. That should be easy enough with a bit of Grep. I could also add links to the crossrefs in the same way (using BBEdit to confirm each change). It would then be easy to query just using a browser's search field.

However, ideally, I'd like something that returned only (all) the matching results. XML/HTML Tagging is the easy bit: the problem is the front-end to access/query it.

I'm on MacOS. *(I'm also investigating Apple's Dictionary format...)*

Any ideas on how to proceed would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge question.  So many choices at so many areas.
A small start:

1. A searchable db. Look at https://solr.apache.org/
2. Php to handle interaction front-end with solr and to serve your html search form and results.